# Stretching a wave maintaing the length and curve

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, graphing-functions

I have a function as ,
 y = [sin(cos(x))]*x

were , 0 <= x <= PI/2

It draws a wave in 
[this manner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7Fep.png)

I am trying to perform calculations which will stretch the or squeeze the wave maintaining the length .

**case**(1) : When x & y increases , the wave should be stretched .

**case**(2) : When x & y decreases , the wave should be squeezed .

[Moving a point to x,y](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pmX6.png)

Reason behind my need : I am developing a simple a game were i am trying to achieve some rope movements were user will be able to control the end points .I might be not maths geek but i would luv to achieve this on my own , any references , i would appreciate it .

Comment: It strikes me that this could be a really difficult problem, not "simple" at all. There are various software packages that are designed to help people create games; some include "rope physics" modules, like this: http://help.yoyogames.com/hc/en-us/articles/216755968--GMS-S-Intermediate-Rope-Physics

Comment: Thx for that reference .I am looking into precalculus more . If i ever finding a solution i need i will post it as answer over here .

Comment: Precalculus offers ways to change the shape of the rope, but it does not give you any way to _maintain the length of the rope_ as you say you want to do. You need calculus in some form or another (either symbolic or numerical methods) in order to measure the length of a curve like this. Another alternative is to model the rope as many short connected segments rather than a continuous function, which I suspect is what the game engines do.